# How to locate duplicate XML elements via Xpaths using Java

Tags: java, regex, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I make a call to an API and I get the following response:

```
<Error>
    <FormCd>940</FormCd>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Balance Due</Key>
            <Value>1500.99</Value>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
 </Error>

 <Error>
    <FormCd>941</FormCd>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Node</Key>
            <Value>/Return/ReturnHeader/Filer/USAddress/ZIPCd</Value>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
 </Error>

 <Error>
    <FormCd>942</FormCd>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Description</Key>
            <Value>Wages Amount</Value>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            <Key>LineNumber</Key>
            <Value>2</Value>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
 </Error>
```

How can I uniquely identify/locate elements within this document via it's common elements using Xpaths. What I mean is, when I make attempt to execute the following Xpath:

```
/Error/FormCd
```

I get an error because there are 3 possible values for this Xpath. Since there are 3 root elements here, I can't do something like this:

```
/Error/FormCd[0]
/Error/FormCd[1]
/Error/FormCd[2]
```

Indexed Xpaths won't work because I have more than 1 root element.

Any ideas how I can manipulate the given XML so I can easily get to the elements I want? Perhaps writing a new XML documents for all responses which have more than 1 root element? And putting it all under 1 root element i.e. Error? This might be too expensive though. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**

Trying to Make my malformed XML into well-formed XML by adding a root tag using following implementation:

```
    try {
        // String f = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(file));

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document oldDoc = builder.parse(is);
        Node oldRoot = oldDoc.getDocumentElement();

        Document newDoc = builder.newDocument();
        Element newRoot = newDoc.createElement("AllErrors");
        newDoc.appendChild(newRoot);
        newRoot.appendChild(newDoc.importNode(oldRoot, true));

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(newDoc);

        File fil = new File("newXml.xml");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fil);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);

        System.out.println(out);


    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error I get is:

```
[Fatal Error] :21:3: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 3; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at com.intuit.ctg.taxengine.automation.calc.ErrorXML.test(ErrorXML.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: Your selection criteria is underspecified, and your XML isn't well-formed.   State specific criteria by which you wish to choose among the `Error` elements, and add a common root element to your XML.

Comment: Yes that is part of my problem. I am calling an API and the API responds me with the malformed XML as shown in the original Post. I want to parse the XML via XPATHs programmatically (java) and retrieve certain values such as ` /Error/FormCd` . perhaps I should enclose the response with a new root node such as `AllErrors` so that way there is only 1 root node. So adding to my criteria, I'd say to make this malformed XML into well formed XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose your response in a new xml node called <root>. Also your xpath is wrong.

```
/Error/FormCd[0]
```

Is not possible because xpath indexing starts at 1. Furthermore:

```
/Error/FormCd[2]
```

Gives you the second <FormCd> element from all <Error>. And as far as I can see you only have one <FormCd> in all your <Error>.  What you should do is this:

```
/Error[1]/FormCd
```

Which gives you all the <FormCd>(in this case one) from the first <Error>

Comment: The problem I have here is because the XML I'm trying to wrap is malformed (due to the fact of having multiple root nodes), which is the problem I'm trying to solve! Circular problem I'm having

Comment: I am not a java developer, so no. But it should not be to hard to add <root> at the start of your file/string and </root> at the end. After that you have a well-formed xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding all the Error elements to a List and then creating a container for it, allows to make the malformed XML, well-formed.

```
List<InputStream> streams = 
        Arrays.asList(new ByteArrayInputStream("<AllErrors>".getBytes()), inputStream, 
                new ByteArrayInputStream("</AllErrors>".getBytes()) );

container = new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(streams));
wellFormedXML = IOUtils.toString(container);
```

From here I can use java's XPATH library to execute XPaths.